# Redis cluster can not auto failed over

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I setup my Redis cluster (version 6.2) with 3 master nodes and 3 slave nodes. It works well for normal scenario.

However, if I kill one of the master nodes, even if I wait a very long time, the auto-failover does not happen. I use the "cluster nodes" command, the output tells me that the killed node is marked as "master, failed", and all 3 slave nodes are still as "slave". From the log, I also can not see any useful information.

My cluster config, except below 2, all are used default:

```
cluster-node-timeout 5000
cluster-require-full-covearage no
```

So may I know who has an idea how to check what is wrong, that is very appreciated!